# Is there a way to map over an array of objects in react and also get the accosiated images from cloudinary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, cloudinary

I am trying to map over an array of objects in react, the object includes a product name and id.  Im using cloudinary to store my images but im not sure what to put as the publicId

Im trying to get the public id associated with each object to pass into the public id

This is my code

```
 <div>
      <Container>
        <h2>My Products</h2>
        <CardDeck>
          {myProducts.map((product) => (

            <Card style={{ minWidth: "14rem" }}>
              <Image cloudName='dgeizgzdw' publicId="equipped/{product._id}" className='card-img-top'/>
              
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{product.product}</Card.Title>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </CardDeck>
      </Container>
    </div>
```

It works when i hard code the product id like so.

```
  <div>
      <Container>
        <h2>My Products</h2>
        <CardDeck>
          {myProducts.map((product) => (

            <Card style={{ minWidth: "14rem" }}>
              <Image cloudName='dgeizgzdw' publicId={'equipped/5f1fcbd42371c61758db2962'} className='card-img-top'/>
              
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{product.product}</Card.Title>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </CardDeck>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
```

Ive tried interpolating the public id the main issue is that the first part of the string 'equipped/ is not saved in the public id

Comment: You don't even need to use component image, you can do it with <img/> tag and as src the link from cloudinary dashboard, you don't need the publicId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<Image cloudName='dgeizgzdw' publicId="equipped/{product._id}" className='card-img-top'/>
```

write:

```
<Image cloudName='dgeizgzdw' publicId={`equipped/${product._id}`} className='card-img-top'/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude, works great, i had the back tics mixed around